# Let G be an abelian group and let H and K be finite cyclic subgroups with |H| = r and |K| = s. Show that G contains a cyclic group of order lcm(r, s).

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be an abelian group and let H and K be finite cyclic subgroups with |H| = r and |K| = s. Show that G contains a cyclic group of order lcm(r, s).

I already try many times.

I don't know how to complete proof.

When I prove this problem, i find error.....

help me.

Comment: If $o(a) = r$ and $o(b) =s$ in an abelian group, then prove that $o(ab) = lcm(r,s)$

Comment: @JordanGlen I have a question.  why  |H∩K|  divides gcd(|H|,|K|) ??

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I tried but I don't solve

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I try gcd(r, s) = d and r = dr_1 s = ds_1 and gcd(r_1, s_1) = 1 then, end... if I keep going I meet contradiction